# Trouble making huffman tree

Tags: huffman-code

I have a simple pattern which is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccdddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffttttttttt"

a:22,b:15,c:13,d:11,e:10,f:8,t:9. Here, the tree I make the root node is 87 while when I use the visualizer it make 88. I don't know if I build the right tree or the visualizer.

Is it okay that these minor differences occur?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not ok. The sum of your frequencies is 88, so if you build the Huffman tree correctly, the root node will have exactly that sum. If it's not, you have a bug.